# When we write socket(family, type, protocol) in c linux, what happens exactly internally?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking

My doubt is how linux kernel handles the socket creation, send and receive of data at kernel level? where can I get the source code for them and learn the internal coding?

Comment: Google for [linux kernel source](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux+kernel+source) gives you *the* website https://www.kernel.org/ right as the first entry!

Answer (score 2):

Linux handles socket's functionality through the VSF (Virtual File System), that's why you can use the *filesystem's* system calls with a socket file descriptor. Before learning about this you should be familiar with Linux's filesystems and VFS.

When you issue the system call, Linux will allocate a *file descriptor* in the process's `task_struct` and associate it with a *socket data structure*. The VFS is somehow *object oriented* and basically a socket structure extends some functionality to use the network protocols on the Linux stack. On this *socket data structure* there's also information and further method extending, conditioned to what protocol the socket belongs to.

There's a lot happening on the background and sure reading the source code will be the best information, also there is a very good literature about this topic: [O'Reilly Understanding Linux Network Internals](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596002558.do).

Hope this helps!